# Room Persistance Error

Tags: android, android-room

I have an app that uses Room persistence at production mode. Its seems when i try to update a table i have the following error on some devices: My connection with database is open all time, only on destroy i release the db.

This is my Service that runs every 12 hours

This is Service: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8fac7650b34aa19229d5f6b91d2454d4
DataRepo :
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/70c524c1e8eb5e7ed893131a9c685b5b
AppDatabase
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ccb20853054fa5d453592fd2653a4dc4

the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.throwIfNotOpenLocked 
    (SQLiteDatabase.java:2199)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.createSession 
    (SQLiteDatabase.java:379)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$1.initialValue 
    (SQLiteDatabase.java:92)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$1.initialValue 
    (SQLiteDatabase.java:89)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal$Values.getAfterMiss (ThreadLocal.java:430)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get (ThreadLocal.java:65)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.getThreadSession 
    (SQLiteDatabase.java:373)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.getSession (SQLiteProgram.java:101)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete 
    (SQLiteStatement.java:64)
    at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete (FrameworkSQLiteStatement.java:75)
     at android.arch.persistence.room.EntityDeletionOrUpdateAdapter.handle (EntityDeletionOrUpdateAdapter.java:69)
      at mbc.analytics.sdk.room.dao.TimeDao_Impl.updateTimeModel (TimeDao_Impl.java:122)
      at mbc.analytics.sdk.room.database.DatabaseRepository.createTimeEntity (DatabaseRepository.java:211)
      at mbc.analytics.sdk.room.database.DatabaseRepository.createAppEntity (DatabaseRepository.java:56)
      at mbc.analytics.sdk.services.LollipopService.getStats (LollipopService.java:202)
      at mbc.analytics.sdk.services.LollipopService.access$900 (LollipopService.java:39)
    at mbc.analytics.sdk.services.LollipopService$2.run (LollipopService.java:153)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
      at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: You should not close the DB in any way. Can you share the relevant code?

Comment: This code is inside a service..

Comment: @XavierRubioJansana check my edit

Comment: can you share also the implementation of `DatabaseRepository`?

Comment: @XavierRubioJansana Check

Comment: This gist will not compile (I guess you edited something, `AppDatabase` import is missing). Anyway, I guess that in `db = AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(ctx);` you're calling `Room.databaseBuilder()`. Can you share `AppDatabase.getAppDatabase()` method?

Comment: @XavierRubioJansana check my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DatabaseRepository` is wrapping a call to `Room.databaseBuilder()`. As this is implemented using a singleton, you're closing the database in the call to `databaseRepository.databaseClose();`, but not opening again. The creation of a new `DatabaseRepository` in your code doesn't help, as `AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(ctx);` will return the same closed database.

So, possible solutions will be:

- Remove the call to `databaseRepository.databaseClose();`, as the service is running inside the same `Application` as the rest of your Activities, and the database is (and should be) shared. **This is the preferred solution in my opinion**.
- An alternative will be that `DatabaseRepository#databaseClose()` also destroys the database object by calling `AppDatabase.destroyInstance();`. To me, this is can pose other issues, like concurrency issues, retained references to the old database object (e.g. in an activity), etc.

Code for the second, **not recommended** solution:

```
public void databaseClose() {
    if (db.isOpen()) {
        db.close();
        AppDatabase.destroyInstance();
    }
}
```